# Achieving Laravel Eloquent Model Inheritance

Tags: laravel, inheritance, model

I currently do have a `vehicles` table that holds "Cars".

Now I want to allow the system to have `Bikes`, `Cars` and `Trucks`.
They have some fields in common (manufacturer_id, mileage, ... ) but they also have specific fields (Bike: cylinder_capacity, seats; Car: doors, ...)

I have tried using all columns in vehicles table and then use the models to handle the differences, But i had problems setting the fillable fields for the child models...

Then I read about polymorphic relations and it seems the right way to go.

So, my questions are: Which approach is the best? What is the best way to implement it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create additional tables:

1. `vehicles_types` to store types, like cars, bikes etc.
2. `vehicles_attributes` to store specific type attributes related via `vehicle_type_id` with fields `vehicle_type_id`, `name`, `value`.

Comment: Just like wordpress does with wp_postmeta? Doesn't this approach create lots of duplicate `key` rows? and isn't it harder for querying later?

Comment: So if would like have less "duplicates" then create tables for each type like `vehicles_bikes` (related via `vehicle_id`) and store additional parameters in them fields. In this approach you have only one additional join.

Comment: I how would I handle the models inheritance in this case? 
inherinting $fillable and so on... I am quite lost for solving this issue

Answer (score 0):

I extend other models occasionally, and it works as expected. The migrations need to be set up separately, but the class logic (attributes and methods) will work in the normal OOP way. If you're familiar with this, just do what you're doing!

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering. So I am still doing something wrong. Let's say a have $fillable = [ 'manufacturer_id'] for `vehicle` and $fillable = ['cylinder_capacity'] for `bike`. 
When I am storing a bike I get  SQL error saying that I am not providing 'manufacturer_id'... Even if Bike extends from Vehicle...

Comment: Inheritance implies that it takes on its ancestors' attributes UNLESS you override them. Fillable means that you can mass assign. Your error seems like cylinder_capacity is a required field on  your vehicle model. You can override that in your bike model.

Comment: What I want to do now is to reuse the parent::$fillable in child's $fillable (and add only the specific ones in child's model).
If I just copy the $fillable from parent, manually add the specifics childs' fields to it and run it works... I just want a way to avoid duplicating the fillable array all over vehicle child's models...

Comment: You'll probably have to do that in the child's constructor.

Comment: Have tried that. Model constructor expects the $attributes... not the fillable keys... I do not know how to get attributes (with values) from Bike model... &#129300;

Comment: Oh, I don't mean that. At the top of the constructor, run `parent::__construct();` and then `$fillable = array_merge($fillable, [your stuff here]);`

Comment: If I call parent::__construct before merging $this->fillable the model tries to do the INSERT without setting the $fillable... which won't work :(